# How to keep a class from being instantiated outside of a Factory

Tags: c#, factory

I have a Factory. I do not want to allow classes that this factory produces to be instantiated outside of the factory. If I make them abstract, static, or give them private constructors then they won't be instantiable at all! Is this a language restriction or what?

I don't want to allow this

```
var awcrap = new Extrude2013 (); // BAD !!!
awcrap.extrudify (); // I don't want to allow this
```

Rest of code:

```
using System;

namespace testie
{
    public enum ExtrudeType { Extrude2013,  Extrude2014 }

    public interface IExtrudeStuff {
        void extrudify();
    }

    public class Extrude2013 : IExtrudeStuff { 
        public void extrudify(){ 
            Console.WriteLine ("extrudify 2013");
        }
    }

    public class Extrude2014 : IExtrudeStuff { 
        public void extrudify(){ 
            Console.WriteLine ("extrudify 2014");
        }
    }
    public static class ExtrudeFactory {
        public static IExtrudeStuff Create(ExtrudeType t) {
            switch (t) {
                case ExtrudeType.Extrude2013: return new Extrude2013 ();
                case ExtrudeType.Extrude2014: return new Extrude2014 ();
                default: return null; 
            } 
        }
    }

    class MainClass {
        public static void Main (string[] args) {
            // Now for the pretty API part
            var o = ExtrudeFactory.Create (ExtrudeType.Extrude2013);
            o.extrudify ();
            var p = ExtrudeFactory.Create (ExtrudeType.Extrude2014);
            p.extrudify ();

            var awcrap = new Extrude2013 (); // BAD !!!
            awcrap.extrudify (); // I don't want to allow this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible. `new` keyword will allow instantiation.

Comment: Why not just make them private nested classes inside the factory class?

Comment: Are you looking for internal?

Comment: @mikez Nested classes can be an eye-sore.

Comment: Or an internal constructor could work. Then no one outside your assembly could instantiate them.

Comment: @RahulTripathi You're supposed to tell me, but no I'm not internal deals with assemblies. Has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You could do it by analysing `StackTrace` trick. It is expensive. Why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: I don't like expensive tricks. I want it prevented because it would break architecute and defeate the whole purpose of factory, allowing an object to be made outside of a factory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't completely disallow this. Whether or not it's a language "restriction" would be a matter of opinion, but there are things that you could consider:

- Make the constructor `internal`. This will allow any type within the declaring assembly to call the constructor, but nothing outside the assembly. This would mean that any code you write in that assembly to be responsible for calling the factory, and it also means that you could not declare subtypes of the class in another assembly, since it would be unable to call the constructor.
- A similar approach would be to make the class you expose *abstract* (or an interface), then declare an `internal` (or even `private` as a subclass of the factory, since it would never be referenced outside of the factory) type that implements the abstract class or interface.
- Require a token that only the factory can provide in the constructor. This is how the `DataTable` class works. While the constructor could still be *called*, the user would have to pass in `null` for the value and it would at least be obvious that they shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: How would a RequireToken be type safe? Or enforced by the compiler? What is the type of the RequiredToken?

Comment: @dave: It can't be *required*, in the sense that the user could still pass `null`. But it would fail at runtime and should be pretty obvious to the person writing the code that they shouldn't be calling it.

Comment: @dave: Also note that if the classes you're using are all in the same assembly, then the first two approaches would be preferable. The last approach is only necessary if you need to allow for subclasses defined outside of the defining assembly.

Comment: It seems that nested subclasses are the only way to enforce this by the compiler.

Comment: If you mean both within and outside of the same assembly, then yes.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But then it becomes verbose

Comment: You can always define the factory class as a partial class and still implement the nested sub classes in separate files.

Comment: Genius. partial classes, you win.

Comment: I could bring my Factory class to inside the package that contains the created objects and then I made the constructor of those objects default (internal). Now, the only way to instantiate a new object is through the factory. Only calling the Factory class which does contain a public constructor can create the restricted objects.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `Factory Pattern` is that only the Factory knows how to choose and make an object and it only exposes the instantiated object's functionality through an interface not a concrete class. Making the object's constructor private fails because `Factory` itself cannot instantiate it.

Solution:

1- Define an `interface` class which all types of the `Extrude20XX` classes implement it such as `IExtrudeStuff`.

2- Wrap the `Extrude20XX` classes inside the class of `Factory` as private nested classes.

3- Implement the interface `IExtrude` in all the `ExtrudeXX` classes.

4- Write a (static) `Create (t)` method like:

```
public static class ExtrudeFactory {
 public static IExtrudeStuff Create(ExtrudeType t) {
 {
   switch (t) {
       case ExtrudeType.Extrude2013: return new Extrude2013 ();
       case ExtrudeType.Extrude2014: return new Extrude2014 ();
       default: return null; 
   } 
 }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution, nested subclasses. What would be nice is to have seperate files for classes like Extrude2013 (that can't be instantiated), then have properties inside the factory for those classes that *can* be instantiated

Comment: @dave Although it is a good practice, distributing the classes across separate files doesn't change anything unless they are in same assembly. The keynote is that they should be private inside the `Factory` class. This way `Factory` class can be partial and expands through out concrete classes.

Comment: Yes completely it will not change the operational semantics of the code, but the difference is readability

Comment: @dave and maintainability :)